# 'split' is not an exported object from 'namespace:data.table'

Tags: r, data.table

running `data.table::split` returns an `Error: 'split' is not an exported object from 'namespace:data.table'`. Any idea why?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`split` is a generic function defined in **base**. Package **data.table** just adds a new "data.table" method to it.

```
## S3 method for class 'data.table'
split(x, f, drop = FALSE,
      by, sorted = FALSE, keep.by = TRUE, flatten = TRUE,
      ..., verbose = getOption("datatable.verbose"))
```

You can go for `data.table:::split.data.table`.

---

> So this behavior is expected? It seems weird to me. Shouldn't `data.table::split` point to `data.table:::split.data.table`?

It might be easier for you to consider `print`. This is also a generic function. Does every package need to redefine it and make an **R** session a mess? No. A common practice is to add a new method by defining `print.xxx`.

Comment: believe so, applying a different method for specific types of arguments: *Method dispatch takes place based on the class(es) of the first argument to the generic function*. Didn't know that this could cause functions not to be found using `::`

Comment: still the manual page is there, that's I guess what confused me. `split` is also in the `data.table` manual index

Comment: @gaut I agree. I think the author should use `"split.data.table"` as the main name of the documentation,

Comment: for example, `forecast::forecast()` is found even though `forecast` is generic

Comment: doesn't it rather come from the `generics` package?

Comment: @gaut What version is your **forecast**? Note that the latest 8.17.0 starts to import **generics**. But versions up to 8.16.0 defined its own `forecast`. See https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/forecast/news/news.html I am using 8.17.0. This explains why we drew different conclusion on function `forecast`.

Comment: 8.16, basically just installed it. That's interesting... but i guess my question holds.

Comment: `urca::summary()` for example is also exported

Comment: @gaut That is S4, not S3. An S4 method should be exported to override S3 one.

Comment: `forecast::accuracy()` is another example I guess